# Thinkpad T15 Gen 2 fail to recover ME Firmware at booting, then Ubuntu 22.04 has no sound

Tags: ubuntu, boot, audio, bios, thinkpad

I have just updated the firmware of my Thinkpad T15 Gen 2 in Ubuntu, however, the next time I start up, I get the following message before booting:

1. "Reading ME Firmware... Please do not power off! 48% Completed"
2. "Recovering ME Firmware...Please do not power off! 10% Completed"
3. "Failed to recover ME Firmware..."

After that I get to the boot page. At this time, the resolution is quite low (so the window appears really large). When I then boot into Ubuntu 22.04.3, everything is normal except that there is no sound, and when I switch the volume the label is "Dummy Output". The real audio device cannot be found. Rebooting or restarting gives exactly the same problem.

I have tried the solutions stated in https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-lenovo/issues/303 and some other relevant methods (for similar devices). However, they did not work.

How to solve this problem and what caused it?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem today and here is my method.

```shell
sudo su
fwupdmgr reinstall
```

Reinstall all 1 to 6 and reboot. Then the problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks! It Worked for me in Manjaro with a Lenovo Thinkpad T14

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this in the terminal:

1. `sudo modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel`
2. `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/sound -name snd-hda-intel.ko`

Lastly, try this approach:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

OR:

```
sudo apt install alsa-utils
```

AlsaProject website: https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work either, even after I rebooted after using the instructions you gave. Does the message before booting provide any clue?